# Power BI - count active items between two dates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a query I tried to resolve but I failed badly.

I have a table with items and want to count active ones per day. I did it in excel where I created another column with the last 7 days and I used countifs.

So my excel formula is

```
=COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$30001,"<="&F3,$B$3:$B$30001,">="&F3)
```

But I need the same in Power BI.

My table with data is called ADW_DEFECTS and has two columns with open and closed dates.

```
ISSUE_DTTM  CLOSE_DTTM
26/11/2019  
26/11/2019  
26/11/2019  
26/11/2019  
26/11/2019  
25/11/2019  
25/11/2019  
25/11/2019  
24/11/2019  25/11/2019
24/11/2019  25/11/2019
24/11/2019  25/11/2019
24/11/2019  26/11/2019
23/11/2019  24/11/2019
23/11/2019  24/11/2019
23/11/2019  25/11/2019
22/11/2019  22/11/2019
```

Now I figure out I need to pivot to another table for the last seven days' calculations (I used a table called NEW.DEFECTS_ACTIVE).

This is the result of excel

```
Dates       Active
26/11/2019  1
25/11/2019  5
24/11/2019  7
23/11/2019  3
22/11/2019  1
21/11/2019  0
20/11/2019  0
```

So, the required result in Power BI is a table with the same as excel one.

Comment: Please let me clarify about the calculation logic. If a record has no close date, doesn't that mean it is still active at the time of data collection? So, when we count the number for 26/11/2019, shouldn't it be 9 (1 closing at 26/11/2019, and 8 not closed yet) instead of 1?

Answer (score 4):

You can also expand the table like this, though you end up with a second table:

```
Expanded_ADW = 
GENERATE(
    CALCULATETABLE(
        ADW_DEFECTS;
        ADW_DEFECTS[CLOSE_DTTM] <> BLANK()
    );
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        GENERATESERIES(
            ADW_DEFECTS[ISSUE_DTTM];
            ADW_DEFECTS[CLOSE_DTTM]
        );
        "Expanded_Date"; [Value]
    )
)
```

Then have a calendar with a 1:* relationship with `[Expanded_Date]`. In a visual table with date from the Calendar tabel add this measure:

```
Active = COUNTROWS('Expanded_ADW')+0
```

Then you have a table like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First I would create a **Dates** table.  There are many ways to do this - for more complex requirements I prefer Power Query but for a simple demo you can go to the **Modeling** ribbon, choose **New table** and enter:

```
Dates = CALENDARAUTO(1)
```

Next review the **Model** view and make sure there are no relationships between the new **Dates** table and your existing **ADW_DEFECTS** table.

Then I would go to the **Modeling** ribbon and choose **New measure**, and copy in this DAX formula:

```
Active =
SUMX (
    Dates,
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( ADW_DEFECTS ),
        FILTER (
            ADW_DEFECTS,
            [Date] >= ADW_DEFECTS[ISSUE_DTTM]
                && [Date] <= ADW_DEFECTS[CLOSE_DTTM]
        )
    )
)
```

This basically says for each row in Dates, count how many rows from ADW_DEFECTS are "Active".  You have to imagine the Measure formula running in every cell of your output visual.  The outer SUMX will calculate a total for all Dates by summing the Date-level results - e.g. how many "Days Active".

Finally add a **Table** visual to the Report view.  Add the Date column from the Dates table and the Active measure. Turn off the Totals if you don't want to show that.

It doesn't produce the extra rows with zeros, e.g. 20/11/2019, but they seem arbitrary.  If they are actually required, just add `+ 0` to the measure formula and filter the Date column on the Table visual.

Comment: Although the requirement is not clear enough, the measure might need to be improved, because there is the problem of double counting. If the report is sliced with entire November 2019, the measure will show 17, even though there are only 16 records in the table. Perhaps the correct approach would be counting the number of the fact table rows, filtering by the date table.

Comment: @ Mike Honey. Thanks for that. It works like magic. @ Kosuke Sakai you are correct. The missing item is to add rows with blank CLOSE_DTTM